# How to show the plugins in the page in joomla

Tags: joomla

I have installed the plugin simple image gallery module in joomla. But i cannot figure out how to show the plugin in the site page, as menu item. Anyone could help me?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot show plugin as menu item, menus can only be associated with components.

Comment: is that a module then you can create an artcile page and include that module in that then assign to menu

Comment: plugin simple image gallery module in joomla ? its a plugin ? normally plugin will trigger based on events or alter the view so basically it cannot assign to menus can u share the link of the plugin ?

Comment: Almost all content plugins have a syntax like {mycontentplugin animals} meaning (say) use the mycontentplugin and display the images in the animals folder.  Have you read the documentation? And have you looked at what it says when you configure it?  e.g http://www.joomlaworks.net/docs/simple-image-gallery

Comment: Hi, I am using the simple image gallery module, but the {gallery}{/gallery} command won't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

If that is module then:

- create an article,
- also create a menu and assign that article to the menu system,
- then inside your article content load the module with their position like this:

`{loadposition your_mod_psoition}`

where "your_mod_position" is the module position. Make sure you have content load plugin enabled.

For more information check last section of this [article](http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-banner-slideshow-module).

If it's Plugin it may have short code for embedding to the page, so you can use that inside your article.

Hope its helps..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what Plugin are you exactly using? There are a view called simple image gallery. Please add a link.

To show the gallery I suppose the plugin has some kind of syntax to do that. In most cases you can find the syntax you have to use in the plugin manager. Backend: Extensions > Plugin Manager.

Then pick a article that you can see in the frontend and put the syntax in there according to the syntax of the plugin.